# Ubuntu installation asks for login and password

Tags: usb

Ubuntu 14.04 live cd asks for password and login upon trying to install or try the live environment. What should I do ?

Comment: Попробуй `ubuntu` логин и тот же пароль

Comment: that would not have introduced all one asks!

Comment: What do you mean ? Explain

Comment: enter Ubuntu,the password field is empty and he throws again to enter the login and password,this indicates an incorrect entry!

Comment: In command-line password field is always hidden, which makes it look empty.  Is that showing up empty in graphical environment  ?

Comment: sudo passwd    ubuntu@ubuntu  enter the new password(the cursor in place) repeat the password again no display

Comment: Not correct. `sudo passwd ubuntu`

Comment: Может проще если я на русском буду обьяснять ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) will help?

Comment: Проще! приду с работы, буду мучить.

Comment: загрузив живую систему при просьбе ввода логина и пароля вошёл терминал и ввёл sudo adduser  своё имя и пароль,повторил пароль,а остальное проигнорировал(телефон,номер дома ,хаты) изменения вступили в силу . стал заходить под своим именем и паролем система пыталась запустить рабочий стол,но опять вышла на введение пароля под моим именем. кстати убунта и пустой пароль вела себя так же!

Comment: не пойму зачем вообще просьба в живой системе логина и пароля,ведь в кубунту нет,минт нет,думаю и в федоре и дебиан не будет,зачем такие заморочки?

Comment: может просто unity не желает загрузиться,хотя фон рабочего стола есть?!

Answer (score 0):

The user name is `ubuntu` and there is no password
http://chronicles.blog.ryanrampersad.com/2010/07/ubuntu-usernamepassword-on-live-cd/

if it's not working try `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2`. You should see a console. 
Type

> sudo adduser (any name you want)

and follow the instructions. Afterwards press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7` and use the info you just created.

Comment: and again it is not entered correctly the username or password!

Comment: try with "edubuntu"

Comment: what is "Edubuntu"?

Comment: if it's not working again try the instructions I just added to my answer to create another one.

Comment: "edubuntu" as user name and no password

Comment: "sudo adduser anyname" will feel!

Comment: use the command "sudo adduser" chose any name and follow the instructions

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: спасибо,буду пытаться!

Comment: всё одно пытается загрузить рабочий стол и выходит на ввод пароля под моим именем!

Comment: sorry but I don't speak Russian language! can you speak English?!

Comment: all one tries to load the desktop and entering the password under my name!

Comment: downloading live system when you request the login and password entered terminal and typed Sudo AddUser your name and password, repeat the password, and the rest is ignored (phone, house, hut) changes came into force. go under your name and password, the system tried to start the desktop, but again entered the password under my name. by the way Ubuntu and a blank password did!

Comment: even with my username and password no launch the desktop!I dropped my hands!

Comment: as I can see using 'ubuntu' and blank password works for you?!  so you just need to proceed and install Ubuntu and you will be requested to add a user name and I'm sure it will work once the installation is finished.

Comment: 4 times I installed and after that the same thing as in the living system,work Desk entrance only via login and password and whatever I typed and will not let me!

Comment: why in Ubuntu there is an option at every startup?

Comment: where did you get the Ubuntu Image? from the official website of ubuntu?

Comment: Yes! even before it was installed and worked fine,but for some reason not updating the kernel. I tried to reinstall and got out a bug!

Comment: excuse me,I need to work!

Comment: it looks like the Ubuntu image you are using was downloaded before and not recently and may has some problems, I suggest download a new image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop this is the Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS I already used this version and it works fine (avoid looking for DVD version 4GB) just download the 1GB image and try it

Comment: Hanzo,comrade,after all, I am using the latest downloaded image!

Comment: I'm at a loss,since many times installed Ubuntu comrades and myself enjoyed it for 4 years,since Cialiy 10.04,but due to the ending support the last updated before the next release Ubuntu ,perfectly working with her!

Comment: I have the image of 12.04,which is installed and works,but for some reason does not want to upgrade to 12.10-13.04-13.10 and 14.04 and beyond?!

Comment: Ok, how did you downloaded the Image? did you used some kind of download manager? (it may corrupt the ISO).. if yes try downloading again the image using the torrent (this how I did it) and use Live USB instead for burning the image. I hope this may help you!

Comment: there is no difference between direct download and torrent,important to verify the hash ,bootable USB flash drive wrote means Ubuntu in the live system,run the BIOS set with the CSS,what's wrong?! we go around the circle and answer I still have not heard constructive!